# How to display terms from a custom taxonomy in a hierarchy AND with custom html markup?

Tags: taxonomy, hierarchical, categories

I've created a custom taxonomy (locations) which is hierarchical, and would like to:
a) display an unordered list that respects the hierarchy
AND
b)customize the display output so that I can specify a custom url

Here's the code I'm using, including the two different ways I'm outputting.

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'taxonomy'     => 'locations',
'orderby'      => 'name',
'hide_empty'   => 0,
'title_li'     => '',
'hierarchical' => 1,
'walker'       => null,
);
?>    

// The following gives me the hierarchical display

<ul class="menu">
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>

// And this gives me the customized links

<?php 
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) { 
echo '<li><a href="http://website.com/?ls=&location=' . $category->slug . '">' . $category->name.'</a></li>';
} 

?>
```

The problem is making BOTH of those things happen.

Any solutions? I'm guessing it might be a custom Walker, but I'm not savvy enough to figure that out without a little guidance!!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with the following Custom Walker:

```
class CustomWalker extends Walker_Category {
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {  
$output .= "\n<li><a href=\"http://website.com/?ls=&location=" . $item->slug . "\">".esc_attr($item->name);
}  

function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {  
$output .= "</li>\n";  
}  
}
```

Comment: You should edit your answer with the full pertinent code (include $args and the wp_list_categories() call), then accept it, so that other users could with the same problem could find it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mis-understanding but you don't need wp_list_categories for this.  (also your coding is missing some details).

Will this work?:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'taxonomy'     => 'locations',
'orderby'      => 'name',
'hide_empty'   => 0,
);
?>    

// And this gives me the customized links

<?php 
$categories = get_categories($args);
echo '<ul class="menu">';
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<li><a href="http://website.com/?ls=&location=' . $category->slug . '">' . $category->name.'</a></li>';
} 
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried that, but it didn't nest the child categories under their parents - it just output a flat list.